# If X~N(4,12). How would I compute P(X < 4) without using a table?

Tags: probability

If X~N(4,12) (normal distribution) and I would like to compute P(X < 4). I would like to *not* use the z-table.

How would I achieve this? Would I just integrate over a region using the normal distribution's pdf?

Comment: The mean is $4$...yes?

Comment: Yep, mean being 4 and standard dev is 12.

Comment: And the definition of the mean is....?

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: So you are asking what is the probability that X is below the mean in a normal distribution. What do you know about normal distributions?

Comment: Well that it is symmetric around the mean...

Comment: Right!  So that means the probability of being below it is....?

Comment: Note:  it's a continuous distribution so $P(X=4)=0$.  Is that what is confusing you?

Comment: Yeah I understand P(X = 4) = 0, but I am looking for $P(X < 4)$. Am I missign something fundamental about normal distributions? :o

Comment: Yes, you are.  For symmetric distributions $P(X>mean)=P(X<mean)$.  But for any distribution $1=P(X<mean)+P(X>mean)+P(X=mean)$ so here we get $2P(X<mean)+0=1\implies P(X<mean)=.5$

Comment: In general:  for any symmetric, continuous distribution $P(X<mean)=.5$

Comment: These seem like important facts my book has not mentioned nor my prof has brought up. >_>

Comment: Go ahead and work the integral so that you believe the result.  But symmetry is one of the most powerful tools in all of probability....it comes up all the time.

Comment: Thank you. This makes sense. However, what it was for a more general number that was not the mean?

Comment: Right.  Well, that's what the tables are for.  There are good numerical algorithms for working with the integral but they aren't trivial.  The key point is that the normal distribution captures a lot of "sufficiently random" behavior (in a sense made precise by the Central Limit Theorem).  So, even though it is hard to compute with, it covers a lot of ground.

Comment: Ah - everything just clicked! In fact, I can say that P(mean - x) = P(mean + x). Generally it is symmetric about the mean. More so, the integral is the same because of the shape of the function - integrating from negative infinity to the mean has the same area as the integral from the mean to positive infinity. Does that make sense?

Comment: That makes perfect sense.  That is exactly what symmetry means in this case.

Comment: Thank you so much, Lulu. \o/